# Display image uploaded to drupal field in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm building an app using the Drupal SDK - everything is great. I have my user log in and successfully upload a photo. However once it's uploaded, I want the image located in the field to display in a UIImageView. I'm using SDImageWeb to get this done, I'm just not sure how to write it? Incoming newb question...

Here is the code that successfully uploads the image to Drupal field called field_profile_photo:

**viewcontroller.m**

```
 [DIOSFile fileSave:file success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"File uploaded!");


        [file setObject:[responseObject objectForKey:@"fid"] forKey:@"fid"];
        [file removeObjectForKey:@"file"];

        fid = [responseObject objectForKey:@"fid"];

        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);


        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        [dict setObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fid] forKey:@"fid"];
        NSLog(@"%@", fid);

        NSDictionary *fidLangDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:dict] forKey:@"und"];


        [userData setObject:@"1" forKey:@"uid"];

        [userData setObject:fidLangDict forKey:@"field_profile_photo"];


        [DIOSUser
         userUpdate:userData
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response) { /* Handle successful operation here */

          NSLog(@"User data updated!");

         }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *err) { /* Handle operation failire here */

          NSLog(@"User data failed to update!");
         }
         ];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to upload file!");
    }];

}
```

When I refresh this view, I now want the photo uploaded displayed in an imageview. I assume it would look something like this? does anyone know how I can make secondLink the URL generated at field_profile_photo? I hope I'm asking this correctly. Help.

```
NSString *secondLink = [self.photoData setObject:imageView forKey:@"field_profile_photo"];

[self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondLink]];
```

I have it written like this in my table cell and it works (in another project), however I'm curious as to how I write it when my imageview is just in a view?

```
NSString *secondLink = [[self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"field_profile_photo"];

        [cell.itemPhoto sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondLink]];
```

Comment: sry but i can't understand your problem and question . can you simplify your questiin & problem

Comment: @MohamadFarhand I want to know how to display the image I just uploaded into the Drupal field (field_profile_photo) in my UIImageView :)

Comment: i think you can notify your view inside  completion of your block and update your uimageview's image.

Comment: @MohamadFarhand I know, but I still need a line of code that pulls the data/url of the image from my Drupal field to my UIImageView?